# Parsing base64 using JSON file in Java

Tags: java, jackson, base64, json

I would like to ask what is the best way sending over base64 encoded binary file via JSON . Is it much more faster to read via url the json file, or read it as a string parameter or convert into an byte format and send it over. Which will actually reduce the overhead of the base64.
Currently i'm using json simple or should i switch to jackson? Any pointers

Comment: Is using plain JSON as `application/json` not fast enough? Do you face any problem that needs solving?

Comment: Try this http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-encode-java-string-send-web-server-safe-url

Comment: Currently i have tested with small size of file i did not see any performance issue, but in real scenario we will be able to receive multiple PDF's converted to base64 via JSON. I'm trying to plan ahead which approach will cut down the overhead of the base64.

Comment: How is a PDF file 'converted to base64 via JSON'? I don't understand your scenario. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Tichodroma :What i mean is that JSON file contain base64 encoded binary file  Example {
  "binary" : "hc3VyZS4="
}

Comment: Should I just have the client upload JSON with the fields encoded in base64, and take the 25% hit? Or should I have the JSON object being represented as some sort of "json" variable in a Multipart/form-data request, and have the binary files to be uploaded as another variable or separate JSON file not together with the JSON data to reduce the overhead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson automatically encodes/decodes to base64, when using data-binding. For example POJO like:

`java
class Binary {
    public int id;
    public byte[] data;
}`

would have its `data` member properly Base64-encoded when writing, decoded when reading.
Implementation is somewhat optimized, and it is quite likely overhead is trivial, unless content is very large. But if you are worried about that you can quite easily measure the overhead with a simple benchmark (I'd recommened using `jmh` if you do that).

FWIW, I have not had any bugs or feedback related to performance of Base64 handling for the Jackson project -- it is not one of commonly encountered issues as far as I know.

Comment: Forgot to mention: even when using streaming API directly (`JsonParser`, `JsonGenerator`), it is easy to encode/decoded binary data: methods with word "binary" in them ('writeBinaryValue()` or such) refer to automatice Base64 handling for underlying value.